# Is « Shepherd One » really used internationally by air traffic control for Pope's flight?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airline-operations, head-of-state-transport

[CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2015/09/22/politics/pope-francis-shepherd-one-visit-united-states/index.html):

> The President flies on Air Force One. The Pope flies on "Shepherd
>   One." That's the Federal Aviation-approved call sign for the Boeing
>   777 in which he'll be traveling around the United States, according to
>   an official from American Airlines, which will be operating the plane.

[Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Shepherd_One):

> Shepherd One is the international call sign of any aircraft carrying
>   the pope onboard. The airline which is used for such transportation is
>   usually Alitalia

[image]
<sup>[Source](http://edition.cnn.com/2015/09/22/politics/pope-francis-shepherd-one-visit-united-states/index.html)</sup>

[Perdue site](https://polytechnic.purdue.edu/newsroom/purdue-alum-honored-fly-shepherd-one) ('Cradle of Astronauts'):

> Flying Pope Francis – Purdue alum honored to fly 'Shepherd One'

From [Crux Now](https://cruxnow.com/papal-visit/2015/09/18/fun-facts-and-more-about-life-aboard-the-papal-plane/) catholic press:

> The plane isn’t really called “Shepherd One.” People in the United States 
>   call it that, but the phrase is a media conceit rather than an
>   actual call sign.

[Ghafla.com](http://www.ghafla.com/10-dangerous-misleading-myths-about-popes-plane-shepherd-one-everyone-has-fallen-for-number-8-photos/):

> Did you know it’s Americans who baptized the plane carrying the Pope
>   ‘Shepherd One’? Well, their very own presidential jet is called ‘Air
>   Force One’ so they thought since the Pope is a shepherd leading the
>   Catholic Church, his plane should be called ‘Shepherd One’.

---

**Question**: Does ATC around the world, starting with Italy and the US, uses the specific call sign *Shepherd One*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [FAA declared](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Notice/GENOT_7340_358_POPE_FRANCIS_2.pdf) that as an official call sign for 2015-09-21 to 2015-10-15.

[image]

The order it cancels (.pdf [here](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Notice/GENOT_7340_357_Pope_Francis_2015.pdf)) had the bottom row filled out wrong (SHEPRD1 and "SHEPHERD ONE" were transposed, and "SHEPHERD" was typoed).

A document released on 2016-05-26 lists it in the "deleted special assignment" table ([here](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7340_2F_Bsc_w_Chgs_1-3_Contractions.pdf)).

[image]

So it's not a permanent reserved identifier in the US; but it might be recurring.

Wikipedia [claims here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alitalia-Linee_Aeree_Italiane) (and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_transports_of_heads_of_state_and_government#Vatican_City)) that in Italy the Papal flights are named "Volo Papale ###", where the ### is a serial number (seemingly the number of times this Pope has flown).  I'll admit that I haven't been able to find anything akin to faa.gov for Italy, France, Australia, or the UK which would corroborate either "Volo Papale" or "Shepherd One".

> Typically, the Pope flies on a chartered Alitalia Jet. The Pope's flight is often nicknamed "Shepherd One" by the press, while the actual callsign is "Volo Papale" (papal flight, in Italian) followed by a serial number.

Comment: Thanks, what about other countries, specially Italy?

Comment: @mins I couldn't find anything solid, but it appears "Volo Papale ###" is what gets used in Italy.  Shepherd One seems to be created by the media and the FAA plays along.  (Updated answer)